# How avoid error on not evaluated code C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, expression-evaluation

Apologies for the most ambiguous and bizarre title.
Suppose we have 2 classes A and B.
class B has interface hasSmth but class A has not.
How to make this code evaluate without compile errors?

```
class A {
    //..implementation
    int id() { return 1; }
};

class B {
    //..implementation
    int id() { return 2; }
    bool hasSmth() { return true; }
};

int main() 
{
    auto obj = someFunction();//returns A or B
    if (obj.id() == 1 || (obj.id() == 2 && obj.hasSmth())) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If the function returns obj of type B, then we are good.
But if it returns obj of type A, compiler will complain about A not having hasSmth, regardless of that part of if never been evaluated.

Can someone give a workaround please?

Comment: "returns A or B" is not possible. All functions must have return type known at compile-time.

Comment: This looks like a possible XY problem situation: https://xyproblem.info

Comment: @M.M The OP could use `std::variant` or something similar?

Comment: The problem is that even if parts of the code isn't evaluated at run-time, it must still be possible to compile. You have to differ between compile-time and run-time.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In that case it would be returning `std::variant` ...  and the problem could perhaps be solved by `visit` or otherwise.  But it's not possible to answer the question until OP specifies `someFunction`

Comment: The `id` functions are quite suspect; it looks like a reinvented wheel. Obviously the classes must be coordinated so that the id's do not overlap, but they're not connected by inheritance.

Comment: I agree with both @jjramsey and @MSalters, selecting code-paths depending on "type" (which your `id` really is) is almost always an anti-pattern. What is the actual problem you try to solve with code like that?

Comment: @M.M, the someFunction() is not related to the problem.
The question is you have an instruction to do if the object is type A or type B and satisfies the boolen interface, how to achieve this without putting in separate ifs and duplication the code.

Comment: @EduardRostomyan In order for `someFunction` to return different types, then it is either doing that using compile time information, or it's using inheritance and returning a pointer/reference to the base class.  Depending on how `someFunction` works will depend on how you write you code in the call site.

Comment: *"the someFunction() is not related to the problem"* - it is the exact *root* of the problem. Were it not the case this question wouldn't even be here. The fact that this is somehow returns two potentially different types is what vaulted this menagerie in the first place. If we don't see *exactly* what you're doing, there is no way we can arrange a possible solution

Comment: could you give a [mcve] next time? The code you give doesn't fully demonstrate your issue. e.g. how does `somefunction()` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone give a workaround please?

Read the declaration of `someFunction` to see what it returns. In the case it doesn't return `B`, then don't write `obj.hasSmth()`. Problem solved.

Now, let's change the question a bit. Let's say that you want to make this work without knowing the return type. Perhaps because rather than `main` you may be actually writing a template that works with different types. There are several approaches, but function overloads are a simple one:

```
bool check([[maybe_unused]] const A&) {
    return true;
}

bool check(const B& b) {
    return b.hasSmth();
}

template<bool returnsA>
void foo() {
    auto obj = someTemplate<returnsA>(); // returns A or B
    if (check(obj)) {
```

Comment: The OP says the function can return an `A` or  a `B`, so they need a way to handle that from the call site.

Comment: @NathanOliver A function can return only one type. I added further instruction to go check which type it is.

Comment: `template <int i = 0> auto foo() { if constexpr (i == 0) return 0; else return 0.0; }` can return two different types.

Comment: @NathanOliver Technically, that's not a function. That's a function template. A `auto obj = foo();` will call the particular instance of that template which always returns `int`.

Comment: @eerorika, the simple answer I was looking for, ty

Comment: @eerorika, if this scales, for example I have family of classes that has the Boolean interface and family of classes that hasn't, should I overload the function for all of them?

Comment: @EduardRostomyan You could have a general template accepting one of those families and specify explicit overloads only for those in the other (smaller) family. A way to avoid specifying overloads for all classes of both families is to do SFINAE magic, but that is complicated. With C++20 concepts, it may become nicer.